# looking to convert first name last name to first initial last name from a getent output

Tags: awk, sed

I have to convert this.

```
getent passwd euser5
euser5:x:12345:20:Ester Jones:/home/euser5:/bin/csh
```

so far i have this.

```
getent passwd euser5|cut -d: -f1,5 |sed 's/:/,/'|tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
euser5,ester jones
```

the final output i need is

```
user5,ejones
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/:[^ ]*:(.)[^ ]* ([^:]*).*/\L,\1\2/' <(getent passwd euser5)
euser5,ejones
```

Comment: I suggest to add `; s/.//` to remove first character.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
getent passwd euser5 | awk -F: '
    BEGIN{OFS=","}
    {
        match($5, /^([[:alpha:]])[[:alpha:]]+ ([[:alpha:]]+)/, a)
        print $1, tolower(a[1] a[2])
    }
'
```

```
euser5,ejones
```